# Regex for skipping certain number of characters from end of a string

Tags: regex

I need a regex to return input string minus certain number of characters from end. Input string will be series of alphanumeric characters (minus space).

For example, when input string is ABC123456789 I want regex to return all but last 4 characters.

Please don't ask why I need a regex for this trivial requirement.

Comment: I have used regular expressions occasionally but this seemed like a herculean task as every search attempt for possible clues resulted in how to validate a string  or number of characters and so on. Not sure why question is down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why substring won't work for you but if regex is must to use then use:

```
^(.*?)\w{4}$
```

And use captured group #1.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQ8vP6/1)